# OpenSSL.Net create certeficate 509x

Tags: c#, openssl

I download this wrapper OpenSSL.Net and I shall integrate in my project which consists in a PKI devellop

- creates certificate personels
- creates a self signed CA certificate
- signed the certificate with the CA I can not find the solution

Answer (score 5):

You can use X509CertificateAuthority and X509Certificate classes to create SSL certificates using OpenSSL.NET programmatically.
You can find the sample code at the [below link.](http://manmoahn-openssl-net.blogspot.com/)

```
###################################################
// Create a configuration object using openssl.cnf file.
OpenSSL.X509.Configuration cfg = new OpenSSL.X509.Configuration("Path to your openssl configuration file i.e. openssl.cnf");

// Create a root certificate authority which will have a self signed certificate.
OpenSSL.X509.X509CertificateAuthority RootCA = OpenSSL.X509.X509CertificateAuthority.SelfSigned(cfg, new SimpleSerialNumber(),"Disinguish name for your CA", DateTime.
Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(365));

// If you want the certificate of your root CA which you just create, you can get the certificate like this.
X509Certificate RootCertificate = rootCA.certificate;

// Here you need CSR(Certificate Signing Request) which you might have already got it from your web server e.g. IIS7.0.
string strCSR = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your CSR file");

// You need to write the CSR string to a BIO object as shown below.
OpenSSL.Core.BIO ReqBIO = OpenSSL.Core.BIO.MemoryBuffer();
ReqBIO.Write(strCSR);

// Now you can create X509Rquest object using the ReqBIO.
OpenSSL.X509.X509Request Request = new OpenSSL.X509.X509Request(reqBIO);

// Once you have a request object, you can create a SSL Certificate which is signed by the self signed RootCA.
OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate certificate = RootCA.ProcessRequest(Request, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(365));

// Now you can save this certificate to your file system.
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Path to your file where you want to create the certificate with file name", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
BIO bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer();
certificate.Write(bio);
string certString = bio.ReadString();
bw.Write(certString);
##############################################
```

Comment: In the current version of ManagedOpenSsl(0.6.1.0) in the ProcessRequest function you should put your Configuration object (openssl.cnf) and the name of the section (like "v3_ca", to get CA:TRUE extension, for example). It was not so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a lot faster if you simply use OpenSSL itself through Process.Start like this:

Create CA:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -out ca.key
openssl req -new -x509 -days 9855 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl x509 -in ca.crt -setalias "Company Name" -out ca.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -name "Company Name" -in ca.crt -out ca_public.pfx
```

Create Signed Personnel Certificates:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -out id.key
openssl req -new -key id.key -out id.csr
openssl ca -policy policy_anything -in id.csr -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -out id.crt -days 3650
del id.csr
openssl x509 -in id.crt -setalias "Personnel Name" -out id.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -name "Personnel Name" -in id.crt -inkey id.key -out id.pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -name "Personnel Name" -in id.crt -out id_public.pfx
```

Comment: thank you
I know but I use C #. net programing as a tool for my project
I find the wrapper openssl.net
I know croi ke implementation for these reason
but I can not find the command
the line of code to create a CA and a certeficat certeficat make personal, then signed the certeficat CA

Comment: Well actually I can't help with that either. Maybe Googling for OpenSSL.Net tutorials may reveal something useful.